# Xdebug trace viewer wanted

Tags: php, xdebug, trace

Does anybody know an actual and convenient XDebug Trace Viewer?

Found several projects on github

https://github.com/search?q=xdebug+trace+viewer

but they does not work propertly or throw an exception on run

Ideally, there would be a phpstorm plugin

but serach on https://plugins.jetbrains.com/ gave nothing too

Answer (score 0):

I try to find a xdebug trace viewer, but there is no useful result, so i write an xdebug trace viewer: https://github.com/kuun/xdebug-trace-viewer.

**Features:**

- Show funcion calls in tree style.
- Statistic time usage for functions.
- Search by function name or file name.
- Show function memory usage.
- Show function call details, include arguments and return value.
- Support multiple platforms.

Hope it is helpful for you.